# File in Use: The action can't be completed because the file is open in Windows Explorer

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

I checked my Windows Explorer and I don't see the file so I am wondering if there is a way to find a particular file or program that is stopping the deletion process from taking place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Common steps that I take when dealing with this problem:

1. Check if its a torrent or something that I am sharing. This is generally the case.
2. Terminate the windows explorer process. Sometimes, if you have opened a window that is lagging or not responding and you force exit then this can happen.
3. A virus scan.

A simple google search found this tool 
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Does exactly what you want. Finds the process that has the file open.